# Opinions on using HTTP request headers to switch between website (HTML) and api (JSON)

Tags: html, json, api, http

We have an ecommerce website that displays groups of products by category using a URL format that maps almost exactly to the REST URL format we would like to use for our forthcoming API.

e.g. `example.com/products/latest` or `example.com/products/hats`

Is it a valid pattern to use the same URL for visible (HTML) and invisible (JSON) results, and to use the Accept http request header to determine what should be returned.

i.e. if you call example.com/products/latest with `Accept: application/json` you get just the product data, but if you use `text/html` you get the full HTML page (header, footer, site chrome etc.)

And if so, is this a good idea - will we run into problems if, for instance, the website needs to change, but the API needs to be stable?

**UPDATE**: some helpful resources - here is an article[1] by Peter Williams discussing the use of the HTTP Accept header to version APIs, and I have also referenced an SO question[2] that reveals some of the problems of using this approach. Probably better to use a custom HTTP header?

[1] Making the case for using Accept: http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/
[2] Problems with jQuery (& IE): [Cannot properly set the Accept HTTP header with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145588/cannot-properly-set-the-accept-http-header-with-jquery)
[3] Making the case for using Accept: http://blog.steveklabnik.com/2011/07/03/nobody-understands-rest-or-http.html
[4] Sitting on the fence: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1566460

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using http headers is generally becoming the accepted way of determining this.

In ASP.NET MVC for example there is an [IsAjaxRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest.aspx) method that checks for the `X-Requested-With` header and if it is equal to `"XMLHttpRequest"` it is deemed to be an ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I tried to do that (and this was a few years ago) I found I could not override the Accept header of an XMLHttpRequest object in Opera. If that isn't a worry for you, then go for it, that is how HTTP was designed to work.

I recommend setting your HTML response to have a higher `q` value then your JSON response though, some browsers send `Accept: */*`.

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with this, but *[Restful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260)* recommends that you version your API via the URL (e.g. api.example.com/v1/products/hats) — I’m not sure that would fit with using the same URLs for the website and the API.

Comment: Yup - versioning would cause problems if done via the URL. I have seen versioning done with headers before, but can't find the reference (and am not sure it's the best way.)

Comment: @HugoRodger-Brown: sure, I guess you could make your API require a custom HTTP header containing the version. (Assuming you want to make sure that people are explicitly calling a given version of the API — if not, then obviously all of this is irrelevant.)