# How to send data from outside site to my server via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I am written the bookmarklet, which takes pictures and videos from a site and must send it to my server via AJAX. The problem is in crossdomain AJAX request - I have got an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysite.com/community/bookmarklet/. Origin http://www.some-nice-site.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

**How to solve data sending to my server from third-part sites?**

Note: I use only plane javascript, this is the stipulation of development.

my code:

```
function getXmlHttp(){
  var xmlhttp;
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {      
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (E) {
        xmlhttp = false;
      }
    }  
  };  
  return xmlhttp;
};

function vote(data) {
  var req = getXmlHttp();
  req.onready = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 & req.status == 200) {
      alert('OK');
    }
  }
  req.open('GET', 'http://mydomain.com/community/bookmarklet/');
  req.send(JSON.stringify(data()));
};

function dataProcessing(){
  //some processing
  return data;
};

// I tried it, but not deeply understand.
function JSONPresponse(){
  document.getElementById('popup_body').innerHTML = 'done!';
};
(function(){
  function pasteIt(){
    // this function is builds the form, which get data for dispatch to my server.
  };

  pasteIt();
  document.getElementById('my_button').addEventListener('click', function()    {vote(dataProcessing)}, false);
}());
```

Comment: A tricky hack might be to use a hidden `iframe` and append the `stringify`-ed text to the `src` URL. Just saying..

Comment: You'll have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for this.

Comment: Instead of using the XHR you'll have to dynamically create a `<script>` element and add it to your page. The `src` of the `<script>` should be something like `"http://ilya.beta.rebelmouse.com/community/bookmarklet?callback=JSONPresponse"` so your server knows what JS `function` to wrap its response in.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite clear... the site you are attempting is prohibiting connection from outside world. You can try by modifying your http headers in request. See:

- [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)
- [Cannot properly set the Accept HTTP header with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145588/cannot-properly-set-the-accept-http-header-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

As @jakeclarkson told - JSON-P is the solution, not the only, but useful for me.

XMLHttpRequest is not needed anymore. Instead it `vote(data)` function creates the script to build URL with params:

```
function vote(data) {
  var script = document.createElement('script'),
  data = JSON.stringify(data());
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'http://mysite.com/api/bookmarklet/?vids='+encodeURIComponent(data);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
};
```

The script is fulfilled, so URL is called and params already in the server.