# how to disable content negotiation with accept_header in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with a link to a controller like `/something/orders.xml` which uses RABL to construct an XML doc. Works, but it seems due to the browser's request header this is being returned as text/html in some browsers, for instance, Chrome:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

I want the response to have `Content-type: text/xml` because that's what it is! So, according to many howtos and the Rails Guides, you can do

```
config.action_controller.use_accept_header = false
```

in `application.rb`. But this is currently resulting in `undefined method use_accept_header=`:

```
/home/sbeam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `use_accept_header=' for ActionController::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to override the content type in the action of your controller by setting `response.headers`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @orders }
  format.xml do
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/xml'
    render :xml => @orders
  end
end
```

**Edit**

The option to set `use_accept_header` was deprecated after Rails 3.0.

If you can't override the format in your actions, you could try modifying your mime types directly. You could put the following into an initializer in Rails:

```
Mime.send(:remove_const, :xml)
Mime::Type.register "text/xml", :xml
```

Also if you are using JQuery and retrieving the XML via ajax, you can explicitly set the content-type you require. See this question: [Cannot properly set the Accept HTTP header with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145588/cannot-properly-set-the-accept-http-header-with-jquery)

**Edit 2**

If all else fails, you can use:

```
ActionDispatch::Request.ignore_accept_header = true
```

in your configuration to turn off content negotiation entirely. You may want to control what the data formats you do want to receive via ajax requests as I mentioned above. If so, then instead you can implement the rack middleware changes at https://github.com/econsultancy/rack-strip_http_accept_headers.

Comment: yes, but I guess the point is that I shouldn't have to (and because this method is actually in an Engine, it's kind of a pain to do this). The client has requested a .xml file, so why do I have to add this boilerplate to force Rails to respond with a header that matches?

Comment: If you want to avoid the boilerplate take a look at respond_with http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

Comment: @max_w the same thing happens with `respond_with`: Rails sends `Content-type: text/html` for all formats.

Comment: @mccannf changing the Mime::Type registry had no effect, it was already `application/xml` to begin with. Seems that Rails ignores it, deferring to the Accept: header.

And this isn't a AJAX call, it's more of an API. In any case, again I'd say that we shouldn't have to depend on headers on the client side either - who knows what some 3rd party will send?

Comment: @sbeam - added something to try if all else fails ;)

Comment: yep, I did eventually find the new `ignore_accept_header` setting and tried it, but... had no effect. It may be some other piece of the stack, I'll have to try and reproduce this on a vanilla Rails app.

Comment: I think you gave the best answer anyone could give to this; even though the problem must lie elsewhere. Thanks for your help