# ember data setting content type to application/html instead of json

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I had declared an ObjectController to edit a post

```
App.PostsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend 
  updatePost: (event)->
    @store.commit()
```

but I see that a html request is being sent instead of a json request, this is from my chrome console:[image: ember data setting content type to text/html]

Is there a way to force the content type as json for PUT request in ember data?

I stepped thru the ember-data code, it was hitting this piece of code, but still the content type for the PUT request was set to text/html(as seen in chrome console)

```
ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    hash.url = url;
    hash.type = type;
    hash.dataType = 'json';
    hash.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    hash.context = this;

    if (hash.data && type !== 'GET') {
      hash.data = JSON.stringify(hash.data);
    }

    jQuery.ajax(hash);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting HTML back because your server returned an error page.

I can see 2 options:

- the request is ok, but there's a problem on the server.
- the request is kind of ok, but lacks of Accepts header (see [Cannot properly set the Accept HTTP header with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145588/cannot-properly-set-the-accept-http-header-with-jquery) ). The server doesn't use the content/type and then returns the html version for this entry point.