# @ResponseBody not return format json error 406

Tags: json, spring, maven, spring-mvc

@ResponseBody can't return forma json and i get Etat HTTP 406 on browser

i am using :
jackson-core-asl 1.9.3 and ajckson-mapper-asl 1.9.3

Getjson :

```
 var p = $.getJSON("natureParOperateur.html", {nomOperateur: $("select#nomOperateur").val()}, function(j) {

}
```

SPRING :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/natureParOperateur.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public @ResponseBody
          List<Nature> natureParOperateur(@RequestParam("nomOperateur") String nomOperateur) {
   List<Nature> listeNatures = metier.consulterNaturesParNomOperateur(nomOperateur);
    return listeNatures ;
            }
```

my servelet-context :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ma.cosumar.web" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="rapport.excel" />

   <beans:bean id="viewResolver1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="order" value="1"/>
            <beans:property name="basename" value="views"/>
  </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

i get on browser by this url :

http://othman-pc.com:8080/dsi/natureParOperateur.html?nomOperateur=IAM

```
type Rapport d''état 406

message

description La ressource identifiée par cette requête n''est capable de générer des réponses qu''avec des caractéristiques incompatible avec la directive "accept" présente dans l''entête de requête.
```

my pom :

<

```
dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
            <!-- Hibernate -->






          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
          </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
                   <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is essentially that Spring doesn't know which converter to convert the response with - this can be fixed by sending an `Accept` header, if you are invoking using a AJAX library, you can use the approach recommended here: [Cannot properly set the Accept HTTP header with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145588/cannot-properly-set-the-accept-http-header-with-jquery)

If you are using a browser get, an option could be to use a .json extension:

Change your requestmapping to not have the .html extension:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/natureParOperateur", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody  List<Nature> natureParOperateur(@RequestParam("nomOperateur") String nomOperateur) {
   List<Nature> listeNatures = metier.consulterNaturesParNomOperateur(nomOperateur);
   return listeNatures ;
}
```

Then a request like this http://othman-pc.com:8080/dsi/natureParOperateur.json?nomOperateur=IAM should internally translate the extension to the appropriate Accept type(in this case `application/json`

Comment: i cant resolve my problem :'( i removoe extension html and also i tested sending an Accept header by ajax i can't produces formt json from ResponseBody

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu i resolve my problem by removing extension html in jsp and also in spring and changingggggg jar of jackson to 1.9.3 asl and mapper thank you so much