# Setting the Accept header in an Alloy UI(AUI) AJAX request

Tags: xmlhttprequest, content-type, prompt, alloy-ui, request-headers

I'm trying to send up a request to my server with the `Accept` header set. The code I'm using looks like:

```
A.io.request(requestUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': acceptHeader
    }
});
```

However, my developer tools show the header has a value of */*, and on the server side when I walk through the property names using `resourceRequest.getPropertyNames()`, I'm not seeing the header as being set. What am I doing wrong here?

Alternately, my underlying goal is to send a ResourceRequest to the server with the desired content type in the Accept header, and then prompt the user to save that resource. Is there a more correct way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score -1):

> I'm trying to send up a request to my server with the Accept header set

```
A.io.setHeader('Accept', '');
A.io.setHeader('Accept', acceptHeader);

A.io.request(requestUrl);
```

> Alternately, my underlying goal is to send a ResourceRequest to the server with the desired content type in the Accept header, and then prompt the user to save that resource.

Use the following process:

- A `<form>` with a method of POST and a target of `_blank` to send the request
- A response with a CONTENT-TYPE header outside of:

  - text/html
  - application/xml
  - application/xhtml+xml
  - text/css
- A response with a CONTENT-DISPOSITION header of `attachment`

**References**

- [Handling MIME Types in Windows Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775148)
- [MDN: HTTP Headers - Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)
- [io/js/io-base.js: setHeader](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/io_js_io-base.js.html#l402)
- [https.request(options, callback)](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback)
- [Cannot properly set the Accept HTTP header with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145588/1113772)