# GET request 'Accept: */*' header is causing a 406. Is it possible to remove it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, http, http-headers

I am trying to GET the binary data of a file from an API; I must make this request using **JavaScript** and I **cannot** modify the API in any way.

I am currently using the following approach;

```
function getUserFile() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: userData.file.link,
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
                request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken);
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                // Do something with data
            },
            error:  function(errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

When I trigger this request from inside the browser it fails and returns a 406. This is occurring because the browser (I believe?) is adding the `*/*` value to my `Accept` header. It must **only** contain `application/octet-stream` for the API to accept the request.

Is it at all possible to remove this extra header value, or disable it from being added to the request in the first place?

**EDIT:** 
Running both [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cshao/9t32qtwn) and the real API call through JSFiddle does not append the `*/*` value to the `Accept` header. Running the same code from a standard `HTML` document does add the value. What is different about these two that might be causing the value to be omitted on one while not the other?

**EDIT:**
The aspx page in question is running either JQuery 1.5.x or 1.8.x

Comment: So you can neither change the code on the client nor on the server? Could you just overwrite `window.getUserFile()` with a new function?

Comment: For the purposes of this question I only have access to the `<script></script>` element of the asp web form I am working on. I do have access to the server-side code but it is legacy and changes are to be avoided unless completely necessary. The API I am trying to communicate with is owned by another company and no modifications can be made unfortunately.

Comment: I made a code snippet and found no `*/*` would be added to the `Accept` header -- the header value is always `application/octet-stream`. Maybe a good idea to check the backend API document? The code snippet is: https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/9t32qtwn/ and I tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari on Mac

Comment: I tested your snippet and found that that you are correct, no `*/*`  value was added to the `Accept` header when run on jsfiddle. However when using the ajax call from inside a `HTML` page the `*/*` value was once again added. I tested this from both a fresh `HTML` document and my current `.aspx` page.

Comment: @Afterfield I made a fresh HTML file and embed the JavaScript code. No `*/*` is added to `Accept` header. Which jQuery version are you using? BTW, you can `@` someone if you want he/she get notified by your comment :)

Comment: @shaochuancs The fresh HTML was using 3.2.1 but I cannot say what version the asp page was using (It appears to differ from page to page.) I'll investigate when I get back to my machine.

Comment: The asp page is running either 1.5.x or 1.8.x. Due to how the project is being build I can't really determine which version exactly is being used at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot properly set the Accept HTTP header with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145588/cannot-properly-set-the-accept-http-header-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not the answer as to why this was/is occurring, I have found a working solution to the problem.

In place of the `$.ajax()` call, I can use a `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
var request;
request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.addEventListener("load", getComplete);

request.open('GET', userData.file.link);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken);

request.send();
```

The 'default' header value was only being appended to my ajax calls; specifically those made from only certain `.aspx` pages.

If I log the request from `beforeSend:` this default header value is already present. Somewhere in the project a setting or a piece of JS is causing the ajax calls to be initialise with the `Accept` header value of `*/*`.

No `$.ajaxSetup({ ... });` is present in the project, and using `delete $.ajaxSettings.headers["Accept"];` makes no difference. My assumption is that the JQuery file being used by these pages contains modifications that affect `ajaxSettings`.

**EDIT**
I managed to track down the `JQuery` file being used by this portion of the asp.NET project. This `JQuery` file had been modified to include certain default when making `AJAX` calls. This is why the direct approach of using the `XMLHttpRequest` was successful.